# how do I transfer data from amazon aws S3 to google cloud storage

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load data from aws S3 to google cloud storage:
- I am using gsutil
- I've made the file on S3 public

on the gsutil command line on a windows machine I entered:

> > python C:\gsutil\gsutil cp https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/myfile.csv.gz gs://my_folder

The error I receive is: 
InvalidUriError: Unrecognized scheme "https"

I have tried substituting http for https

I have successfully uploaded from my local computer to google cloud storage substituting in a local file.

Thanks.

Comment: You might have to downlo

Answer (score 0):

http or https are not supported by gsutil command. Try...

```
python C:\gsutil\gsutil cp s3://my_bucket/myfile.csv.gz gs://my_folder
```